# Как выполнять какие-то действия(допустим Toast) когда изменяется текст TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-toast

Мне нужно отследить изменение TextView и когда он изменится показать тост. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Может быть `EditText`? `TextView` меняет само приложение, то есть вы знаете, когда это произойдет

Comment: @Dareten Нет, именно TextView. Удобнее через слушатель)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляете слушатель на ваш TextView (так же работает и для EditText если замечание @Dareten верно) и в одном из методов показываете свой тост.

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```